# Why do I get the `type is undefined` error when trying to instantiate a component declared in an Angular library?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, micro-frontend

Using nx I have created an angular application with microfront end architecture. It consists of the host app, a couple of remote apps and three angular libraries. One is Core which is imported only into the module on the app host. And two sharing libraries `shared/common` and `shared/common-ui`

[image]

In the `shared/common-ui` library I have created some components that I plan to use in the apps. I have made sure that these components are declared and exported in the shared-common-ui module which in turn is imported by `shared-common`. Being the latter the module that is imported from the apps

[image]

But when declaring a component created in `shared-common-ui` I get this message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: type is undefined
getComponentDef@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:2171:3
extractDirectiveDef@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:2001:10
extractDefListOrFactory/</<@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:2229:108
extractDefListOrFactory/<@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:2229:85
createTView@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:11144:59
getOrCreateComponentTView@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:11093:24
createRootComponentView@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:13170:47
create@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:13056:52
createComponent@http://localhost:4200/node_modules_angular_core_fesm2022_core_mjs.js:22983:43
activateWith@http://localhost:4200/default-
```

This is the content of shared-common module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyModule,
    TranslateModule,
    SharedCommonUiModule, // <---- component with components to use
    SharedPrimengModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyModule,
    TranslateModule,
    SharedCommonUiModule,
    SharedPrimengModule,
  ],
})
export class SharedCommonModule {}
```

When I try to instantiate a component defined in the shared library I get the message described above

Thanks in advance for any ideas

**Update 0**

I have managed to make the component created in `shared-common-ui` show up in the apps. For this I have exported the components via the index.ts file in this location `libs/shared/common-ui/src/index.ts` as follows

```
export * from './lib/shared-common-ui.module';
export * from './lib/components'; // <--- added this line
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I consult it because the module that in turn exports the components is already being exported. I thought this should work without this new export

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

import * as fromComponents from './components';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [...fromComponents.components],
   imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink],
   exports: [...fromComponents.components], // <--- exporting componentes
})
export class SharedCommonUiModule {}
```

What have you seen of components?

```
import { ViewMainContextComponent } from './view-main-context/view-main-context.component';
import { ViewLocalContextComponent } from './view-local-context/view-local-context.component';

export const components: any[] = [
   ViewMainContextComponent,
   ViewLocalContextComponent,
];

export * from './view-main-context/view-main-context.component';
export * from './view-local-context/view-local-context.component';
```